# Google Maps: Populating related marker(s)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am working on a site that brings in a storefront and related employees.  I have successfully populated my back-end with markers for both the storefront and addresses of related employees (consultants that want it advertised).

I can populate both markers simultaneously, but what I am looking to do is have an event listener; when a user clicks on a storefront marker, the markers set up for the employees related to that store will populate onto the map.

Has anyone accomplished such a feat?  I will share appropriate code when this task is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly each store would need to have an array of employees.

When a store marker was clicked you would do the following:

1. Clear all current employee markers on the map.
2. Loop through the employee array associated with that store.
3. Create a new marker for each employee and add it to the map.
4. Store each new marker in an employee marker array so they can be easily removed later.